# How usual is it for languages to have multiple contrasting "neutral" vowels?

Tags: phonology, cross-linguistic, vowels

First of all, I used scare quotes on "neutral" because I can't think of a better word. I was going to say "central vowels" but that would cover some "a"-like vowels whereas I am only thinking of "schwa"-like vowels. Anyway, on with the question...

- In English we have `/ə/` in words like "the" (mid-central unrounded).
- In Bulgarian there is `ъ` → `/ɤ/` (close-mid back unrounded) or `/ɐ/` (near-open central).
- (Hebrew has `ְ`, the source of the English word "schwa", but [it probably doesn't fit my idea of "neutral vowel"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shva)).
- (In Japanese "i" becomes "neutral" after "sh" and "u" becomes neutral after "s", but I don't know whether they're the same or different.)
- In Korean there is `ㅡ` → `/ɯ/` (close back unrounded).
- In Russian there is `ы` → `/ɨ/` (close central unrounded).
- In Turkish there is `ı` → `/ɯ/` (close back unrounded).

Of course many languages have no such vowels at all, such as Georgian, Italian, and Spanish.

*But*

- In Romanian there are two contrasting sounds, each with their own letter(s): `ă` → `/ə/` (mid-central unrounded) **and** `â`/`î` → `/ɨ/` (close central unrounded).
- Also Azeri has two letters, `ə` and `ı` but I couldn't find good info on the vowel phonology if they represent the same sounds as in English and Turkish.

So how unique is the case of Romanian in having two of these "neutral" or "schwa-like" vowels? Is Azeri another example? Are there other well known languages? Little known languages?

Comment: Amharic has /ə/ and /ɨ/, traditionally transcribed as 'ä' and 'i'.

Comment: I just found an interesting related article on the Romanian vowels: [On the origins of /ɨ/ in Romanian](http://conf.ling.cornell.edu/plab/abstracts/RENWICK_Origins_barred-i_Romanian.pdf) (It's a PDF.)

Comment: As far as I know, 'schwa-like' doesn't have a clear definition, so it's not clear what you want to include or exclude--can you indicate this more clearly?

Comment: Just to add, English has /ə/ and /ʉ/, is that the kind of thing you're after?

Comment: I think you need to define "neutral" to get any meaningful answer. If you mean the results of vowel reduction, English has several (probably depending on the speaker): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_and_vowel_reduction_in_English

Comment: @dainichi: I tried to illustrate with examples, since I didn't know the best term to use I also didn't know the best definition. But I could put all that part into a new [tag:terminology] question if you think it would help.

Comment: Haha!  All my vowels are schwas!  My accent is ənəmətəbəl.

Comment: Əvən məə dəphthəngs ər schwəs d-: Seriously though I'm thinking about a rewording. I have a very crappy intermittent connection but I'll be back to hit the edit button after I mull it over long enough...

Comment: Azerbaijani letter ə is nothing like /ə/ in standard Baku accent and it is a strong vowel, not a reduced one. It is pronounced /æ/. Azerbaijani ı is anything between /ə/ and /ɯ/.

Answer (score 2):

It seems there are two questions here: central unrounded vs. reduced ones.

Vowel reduction usually co-occurs with centralization and loss of roundness. It make sense because when spoken in a natural speed, there's no time to articulate it properly.

In Russian, unstressed vowels may reduce significantly, but it applies to *any vowel*, not only `ы`:

молоко `[mə lɐ 'ko]` (milk)
невозможно `[nʲe vɐz 'moʐ nɐ]` (impossible)
жалеть `[ʐɨ ˈlʲetʲ]` (to be sorry)

The vowels in first syllables are retracted to almost nothing, depending on a local dialect.

---

Maybe a good example is Thai. As many languages, it has an effect of **epenthesis**, an insertion of a vowel.
Usually, it is `[a]`:
ขนม `[kʰà - nǒm]` (dessert) - note that no vowels are written, but the 2nd one is phonetically much longer;

But it can be `[ɔ]`:
บริการ `[bɔ̀ - rí - kaːn]` (service)

See [this article](http://www.thai-language.com/id/830222), sections III.b and IV.a

Comment: I thought of going with "central" too but when I looked up each one in Wikipedia it turned out of them are not central. Do you think I should reword it to "schwa-like"? Because to a naive armchair linguist like myself, even though I can here some differences at least in the languages I've played with a little, they all sound "something like schwa" or "indistinct" to me. I'm in Romania again now and though I can produce the two sounds when pushed and can hear the difference when I listen hard, I still mix them up when I'm not putting in effort.

Comment: To me, "schwa" is very descriptive, but it usually means `[ә]`, while the subject of the question is much broader. But again, I'm not a linguist as well, so maybe there's a better term.

Answer (score 2):

Vietnamese has four “central” vowels, orthographic â, ă, ư, ơ. There are at present two conflicting analyses. One group of scholars says that â, ă are a higher and a lower central vowel, and ư , ơ are a higher and a lower back unrounded vowel, but others say that â, ă are short central vowels and ư , ơ are long central vowels. Both theories have their strengths and their weaknesses.

There is a rather detailed discussion here: http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2727474